# Pig can't resolve class version for CassandraStorage

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

After adding Cassandra's lib directory to PIG_CLASSPATH, I tried to refer to org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage. However, I get the following error about class version numbers:

Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
 pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1069: Problem resolving class version numbers for class org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1571)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1544)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix by downgrading to Cassandra 1.2.1, which was built for Java 6.